# Username Password Regular Expression

Tags: ruby, regex, passwords

I'm trying to make a regular expression to match a username password pair on files, that have at least 1 uppercase letter, 1 downcase letter, 1 number and 1 symbol. I'm using the following regex:

```
\b(([a-zA-Z0-9]){5,20}((\\\\=)|( ?([=:]|(->)) ?)|( =\\))((?=.[a-z#{@specialDown}])(?=.*[A-Z#{@specialUp}])(?=.+[0-9])(?=.+[\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+\|\~\-\=\\`\{\}\[\]\:\;\'\<\>\?\,\.\/])).{8,20})\b
```

the specialDown and specialUp variables are special letters in downcase and uppercase respectively.

The problem here is that I'm getting passwords with whitespaces, which I don't want.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you really store username with their clear password in a text file?

Comment: `^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W).{8,20}$`

Comment: No, obviously not, it's for a project. I have to find passwords in the clear that shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace all `.` in your regex with `[^\s]` or `\S` to exclude whitespaces from being matched. Also, you have several `?` patterns, they also allow spaces. Please check if they are necessary.

So, the fixed pattern will look like this:

```
\b(([a-zA-Z0-9]){5,20}((\\\\=)|( ?([=:]|(->)) ?)|( =\\))((?=[^\s][a-z#{@specialDown}])(?=[^\s]*[A-Z#{@specialUp}])(?=[^\s]+[0-9])(?=[^\s]+[\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+\|\~\-\=\\`\{\}\[\]\:\;\'\<\>\?\,\[^\s]\/]))[^\s]{8,20})\b
```